# WPF: Changing an item in a collection observed by ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listview, observablecollection

I have a `ListView` (with a `GridView`) bound to a collection of items. This is pretty standard stuff. The collection is an `ObservableCollection`.

Now let's say I change some property of an item in the collection. How do I tell the `ListView` about this? The list is tens of thousands of lines long, so I need to be able to tell it not to reload the entire collection, just that I updated some single element.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your objects implement some kind of property change notification (the most common way is to implement the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`) - then the list will know to update the property change automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, as you can see from stepping through the code, is no one is listening to for `PropertyChanges` on your individual items.
You need to bind each row (item) of your collection to the `PropertyChanged` event and the easiest way to do this is by overriding `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: Here is another way to do it in XAML with templates- http://www.wblum.org/listbind/net3/index.html